# Django - How turn string to link in template?

Tags: django, django-templates

There is a model with name and link to their profile:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

The table has the below values:

```
name: Alex
Link: www.example.com/alex

name: Jo
Link: www.example.com/jo
```

In template I would like to get the hyperlink to the profiles. I tried the below, but got wrong link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Person</title>
</head>
<body>
Name: {{ name }}, <a href="{{ link }}">Profile</a>
</body>
</html>
```

It gives the link but the string is added to the end of the website address like this:

```
http://www.website.com/person/www.example.com/jo
```

How is it possible to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the https:// or http:// to your link

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
link = models.URLField(max_length=200)
```

Get more reference on:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/